# Barcode Generation PHP (Code 39) Recommendations

Tags: php, barcode

Can anyone recommend a free barcode generation program that is NOT "PHP Barcode Image Generator v1.0"? (People have had problems scanning them).

I would need it to also support separate barcode and label attributes.

It would also prefer it works well with CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library would suit your needs: http://www.barcodebakery.com

It supports multiple kind of 1D barcodes. It also has the possibility to add labels around the barcode as you wish.

It's free for a non-commercial usage.

Comment: I like this library, but there is no way to set width + height so I can have a consistent width/height for barcodes.

Comment: You can use setThickness() which controls the height, the width is determined by the length of the text you want to parse. So this means the size should remain the same across all your barcode if you encode same length of strings.

Comment: Thanks, I zerofilled my barcodes to be same length.

Answer (score 2):

I use [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) library for generating pdf with code-128 and qr-code labels and it works amazing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to work with Code39 it is simply a matter of using a Code39 font (there are several free ones available) and appending an * on each end. For example, if the following were printed using a Code39 font it would be perfectly readable barcode:

```
*YAY-BARCODE*
```

One easy way to do this is either to add them together in a spreadsheet cell. If you have the number you want coded in cell A3, then the barcode cell should be

```
="*"&A3&"*"
```

Or in something like PHP you will want to set the code using @font-face and then tie it to a class (say "barcode"). So your CSS file will have something like this:

```
@font-face      
    {
    font-family: bar;
src: url('bar.otf');
}

.barcode    
    {
    font-family: bar;
font-size:18pt;
padding: 2mm;
vertical-align:center;
}
```

Then to make the string you want printed will look like this where $id is the variable:

```
$barcode="*".$id."*";
```

If that's not clean enough for you, there is a small script you can write to output the barcode as an image using imagettftext().

Answer (score 0):

if you are putting the barcode into a pdf file, you could use an extension like this.
it has worked great for me

http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/68/

Answer (score 0):

1. always generate barcodes in pdf format so that they printout consistently and predictably.
2. mpdf is a pdf creation library for php that can generate many kinds of barcodes including code39.
3. tcpdf works well to create 2d barcodes like qrcode and pdf417.